# Tangent Line to the curve that is Parallel to the line part $2$

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the tangent  line to the curve $y=x^2-1$ parallel to  the line $2x+y=6$.

Hello, can someone can help me with this? Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the slope of line $2x+y=6$ is $-2$, we left to find the derivative of $y=x^2-1$, which is $y'=2x$, and put $-2$ instead of $y'$(why we do that?).

$$-2=2x$$

$$x=-1$$

Substituting $x=-1$ into  $y=x^2-1$ we get $y=0$, and we have a point $(-1,0)$ with a slope $m=-2$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. I am stuck in the point (-1,0), and i really dont know  what to do next.

Comment: Use the line equation formula: $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ and put $x_1=-1$, $y_1=0$ and $m=-2$. What you get?

Comment: Ill comment my answer in few minutes

Comment: Is the answer y= 2x + 2 ?

Comment: No, that is not the answer. Two lines are parallel if they have the same slope. But your equation is with slope $2$.

Comment: Huh ? What do you mean ?  I thought that the slope is -2.

Comment: Substitute again.

Comment: Sorry i cant understand coz this is new to me

Comment: The line equation is: $y-0=-2(x-(-1))$ or...
$y=-2(x+1)=-2x-2$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

The slope of the line $2x+y=6$ is $-2$.  Two lines are **parallel** if they have the **same slope**.  What construction in calculus gives you the slope of a tangent line to a point on the graph?